uniqueness of axis-angle decomposition
I know that it takes three real numbers to specify an element of ${\rm SO}(3)$, which can be thought of as two numbers to specify an axis and a single number specifying the angle of rotation. However I might also think that it suffices to specify a final orientation in order to specify a rotation. If the initial state of my vector being rotated is $\hat z$ direction, then after rotation it will be some other vector still living on the 2-sphere. Therefore I need only two numbers to specify the rotated vector, which is one less than the number of quantities needed to specify a rotation matrix. Presumably this is because there is a family of rotation matrices parameterized by a single number, which all map a given initial vector to a final vector. How can I find this family for a particular final vector (if my initial one is $\hat z$)?

"I know that it takes three numbers to specify an element of ${\rm SO}(3)$" Careful: what types of number?

"Therefore I need only two numbers to specify the rotated vector, which is one less than the number of quantities needed to specify a rotation matrix."  Yes this is true.  But the rotation of a single vector does not uniquely define a rotation.  A rotation (i.e. element of $SO(3)$ rotates every vector about the same axis and angle.  To uniquely determine that you need at least 3 parameters.
